# Color column and exclude NA with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, join, colors, na

I would like to color a column but render the `NA` values one specific color with `ggplot2` please.
If we take the `world` dataset from the `spData` package.

```
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2018) # set seed for reproducibility
(bb = st_bbox(world)) # the world's bounds
random_df = data.frame(
  x = runif(n = 10, min = bb[1], max = bb[3]),
  y = runif(n = 10, min = bb[2], max = bb[4])
)
random_points = random_df |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = "EPSG:4326") # set coordinates and CRS

p1 <- ggplot(world) + 
  geom_sf(color = "gray", fill = "white") +
  geom_sf(data = random_points, color = "black", shape = 4, lwd = 3) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) 

p1
```

[image]

I want only points that are on land

```
world_random = world[random_points, ]
nrow(world_random)
random_joined = st_join(random_points, world["name_long"])
```

My attempt:

```
random_joined$name_long = as.character(random_joined$name_long)

p1 <- ggplot(world) +  
  geom_sf(color = "gray", fill = "white") +
  geom_sf(data = random_joined, aes(fill = name_long), shape = 16) + #,  color = "white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "yellow", "red", "orange", "white")) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA)

p1
```

[image]

How do I show the named countries in different colours and the `NA` on one color?
I would prefer to not use `scale_fill_manual` but another method that *programmatrically understand the value* is `NA` or a country name please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have set `shape=16` for your points you have to map on the `color` aes as `shape=16` does not support the `fill` aes and use `scale_color_manual`. And if you want a specific color for the `NA`s you could do so via the `na.value=` argument of `scale_color_manual`.

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(world) +
  geom_sf(color = "gray", fill = "white") +
  # Map on the color aes
  geom_sf(data = random_joined, aes(color = name_long), shape = 16) + # ,  color = "white") +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("blue", "yellow", "red", "orange", "white")
  ) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA)

p1
```

[image]